# Algorithm to generate unique (possibly auto incremented) ids

Tags: algorithm, unique, uniqueidentifier, random

I need to generate unique ids for my application and I am looking for suitable algorithms. I would prefer something like this --

`YYYY + MM + DD + HH + MM + SS + <random salt> + <something derived from the preceding values>`

F.ex. -

`20100128184544ewbhk4h3b45fdg544`

I was thinking about using `SHA-256` or something but the resultant string should not be too long. I could use `UUID` but again, they are too long and they are guaranteed to be unique on only one machine.

I would welcome suggestions, ideas. My programming language is Java.

**Edit:** The ids need not be cryptographically secure. I am looking at simpler hashing algos like the one by Dan Bernstein, etc.

Comment: UUID is guaranteed to be unique *universally*. It uses the MAC address in the algorithm to ensure no two machines generate the same UUID.

Comment: What's wrong with GUID? It's not much longer than the example you gave, and a GUID is unique

Comment: @Kenny: Afaik no one uses the first version (the one with MAC addresses) anymore. Kinda beside the point anyway since many NICs nowadays have user-configurable MAC addresses. Most UUIDs I see today are version 4.

Comment: Whilst the algorithm attempts to ensure that a UUID / GUID is Unique, there is a mathematical percentage chance that it can occur, but it is in the 1 in multiple Billions range. The MAC address component was removed in later variations of the algorithm, to prevent GUID's being traced back to Mac Addresses - it created a privacy issue.

Comment: Your requirements needs clarification: do you need this to be cryptographically secure and unique or simply unique?  In other words, would a potential attacker crafting a "unique" ID be a threat or not?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's impossible to generate a *guaranteed unique* value, as there is an infinite number of objects that could be constructed (and limited space to store the resulting ids) - you're after something with sufficient entropy to be _virtually_ unique, and for this I'd go with a UUID (and base64 encode it if I needed it to be a bit shorter as a textual representation)

Comment: @John: Ah you're right. Unfortunately I can't edit the comment anymore. Version 4 of UUID depends solely on a PRNG, btw.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with the question and why people are down-voting it. If the wording is not right I can fix it...

Comment: @Andrew:  Try 1 in billions of billions of billions.  @Baishampayan:  Probably because this question is asked almost every other day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have finally settled for this -

```
d = YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
hash = d + sha256(d + random_salt)[:10]
```

Thank you all for the response.

Comment: You would be better off removing the date prefix and adding another 14 characters to the sha substring - each character of SHA256 output adds substantially more entropy than a character of datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
java.security.messageDigest()
```

Comment: WHich is another way to run MD5 or SHA-1, no?

Answer (score 0):

You could use that SHA-256 and then only take the first 10 bytes from the result (or however many you like, balancing length and uniqueness however you like).

Answer (score -1):

I think if you use SHA1(MD5(YYYYMMDDHHMMSS + YourSystemName + ClientName)) u'll be fine with 40 chars.. ;)

Comment: `SHA1(MD5(...))` is useless; if you were to go down this route just use SHA1.